# jquery animate lag issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have a contentSlider with width 200% and i am trying to use .animate to slide the content left and right. But during animation, there is some degree of lag. Here is my animate code.

```
                    $("#contentSlider").stop().animate({
                        left: "-100%"
                    },{
                        duration: 1000,
                        easing: "linear",
                        complete: function(){
                            $("#"+page).remove();
                            $('#contentSlider').css('left', '0px');
                            pageID = clickedID;
                            page = pageName;

                            if($("#audioControl").hasClass('audio')){
                                enableCowSound();
                            }else{
                                $(".moosound").off('hover');    
                            }
                            $(container).removeClass('animating');
                        }
                    });
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: can u put ur code in jsfiddle.

Comment: Sometimes explicitly stating the position value[relative, absolute, ..] inline or in a stylesheet helps me with jquery laggy animations.

Comment: this link help u: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613498/how-to-prevent-this-strange-jquery-animate-lag