# Trying to build a button to expand a list in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build in a button to expand a list in a list of div elements.

```
$('.expandAllfixVersionList').click(function () {

                $('.fixVersionList').find('.issue').animate({height: $('.fixVersionList').children('.version')[0].scrollHeight}, 500);
                $('.fixVersionList').find('.issue').animate({'overflow': 'visible'}, 500);

            });
```

Here I got the problem that he shows the first `fixVersionListElement` correct and all folowing get the same height, even if they got more or less Issues in them. So they might get cut off or be way to big. Can I make this in a way that he addresses the animation dynamic to the correct height?

The structure of the HTML is like this:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="fixVersionList">...</div>
    ...
    <div class="fixVersionList">
        <ul class="issue">
            <li>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="issue">...</ul>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Put a working snippet in your question

Comment: Also checkout slideToggle(), shown example below in answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I recreated your existing code, please let me know if this helps you

```js
$('.expandAllfixVersionList').click(function () {

  $('.fixVersionList').each(function( index, value ) {
  $(value).find('.issue').animate({height:  $(value).children()[0].scrollHeight}, 500);
  $(value).find('.issue').animate({'overflow': 'visible'}, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
.issue{
  height:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="expandAllfixVersionList">asads</button>
<div class="content">
    <div class="fixVersionList">
        <ul class="issue">
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="issue">
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="issue">
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="fixVersionList">
        <ul class="issue">
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="issue">
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="issue">
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its very helpful thanks! In my case i additionally got multiple <div class="fixVersionList"> with different numbers of issues.

Comment: @FrankS. is this what's needed?

Comment: Still got the same Problem: the 2nd fixVersionList gets cut off because its bigger (got more issues). Im guessing this Part is wrong: $(value).find('.issue').animate({height:  $('.fixVersionList').children()[0].scrollHeight}, 500);

Comment: I still have problems with this, now i only get shown one issue when i click the expand button. I also tried parent instead of children in the animation but it gets way to big. Which element is $(value).children()[0].scrollHeight adressing?

Comment: @FrankS. Without a jsfiddle or codepen containing the actual issue, I can help you only upto this level.

Comment: @FrankS. Took a lot of time but finally made it https://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/fmggnrao/4/ This fiddle contains css fixes and javascript fixes for the issues, please check it out. https://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/yydaf2w4/1/ for only the expand all fix. Thanks for the fun project

Comment: @FrankS. please look into [jquery animate stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613498/how-to-prevent-this-strange-jquery-animate-lag) if we do the animation multiple times, there is some sort of lag in the page

Comment: Thanks again, the solution from your fiddle is better. The animate stop is also good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Naren Murali´s answer i managed to get it working with this:

```
$('.expandAllfixVersionList').click(function () {

                $('.fixVersionList').each(function( index, value ) {
                    var count = $(this).find('li').length;
                    $(value).find('.issue').animate({height:    $(value).children()[0].scrollHeight*count}, 500);
                    $(value).find('.issue').animate({'overflow': 'visible'}, 500);
                });
            });
```

Im gonna accept your answer, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify your code a bit, you can also use slideToggle(). First list is has more items to show, you won't have to worry about figuring out what height to animate.

```js
$('.expandAllfixVersionList').click(function () {

  $('.fixVersionList').each(function( index, value ) {
      $(value).find('.issue').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.issue{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="expandAllfixVersionList">toggle</button>
<div class="content">
    <div class="fixVersionList">
        <ul class="issue">
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="issue">
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="issue">
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="fixVersionList">
        <ul class="issue">
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="issue">
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="issue">
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```